# How to get Revit export image coordinates or reference point?

Tags: revit-api, autodesk, revit

I want to have a reference point or to know the coordinates of any point on an exported Image (from any view) from Revit.

For example in the attached image exported from Revit, I'd like to know the bounding box of the picture or the middle point of the picture (in X,Y coordinates) or any other reference point.

[Plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pLC3.jpg)

Is there a way to extract the bounding box coordinates of the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest defining two diagonally opposite points in your image file that you can identify precisely in your Revit model. Determine their image pixel coordinates, export their Revit model coordinates, and use this information to determine the appropriate scaling and translation.

The [RoomEditorApp Revit add-in](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RoomEditorApp) and its corresponding [roomedit CouchDb](https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit) web interface demonstrate exporting an SVG image from Revit, scaling it for display in a web browser, and transformation and calculation of exact coordinates back and forth between two environments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jeremy, I'm looking into that. I've notice the BoundingBoxUV in the view Im exporting changing based on the elements on the edges of the view, is this boundingbox can help me determine the exported image bounding box? The units are different than the "specify coordinates at point" so Im not sure.

Comment: They might certainly be useful, and almost equally certainly they will not enable any precise transformation. Therefore I would still stick with my suggestion.

Comment: Working on your suggestion, how do I determine image pixel coordinates for an element? I can get their Revit coordinates, I know the amount of pixels the picture contains.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed. In my solution, I exported the SVG data myself from my own add-in, so I knew exactly what the limits of the SVG data were. How are you exporting your image? You could create your own screen snapshot programmatically and use the [UIView](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/2a070256-00f0-5cab-1412-bee5bbfcfc5e.htm) Revit model coordinate transformation to device pixel coordinates to determine it:

Comment: This code is for Design Automation on forge, so UI functions are not allowed. I export an image with doc.ExportImage and setting the amount of pixels, FitToRange etc. I was thinking about getting the view Cropbox, that is what is exported in the image as I understood and that's how I'll get the boundingbox of the image and since I know the amount of pixels I can calculate how many pixels are there for each unit of dimension.

Comment: Outline (as BoundingBoxUV), not the Cropbox, sorry.

Comment: This indeed worked well. I got the view Outline, transformed it and could determine the amount of pixels to set based on that. That way I could get reference point (any points of the bounding box) and I know the amount of pixels. I encounter a minor issue, the image contain Elevation markers at the edges of it - I managed to "catch" them and hide them via the code, But there are still Elements at the edges marking North/South/East/West and Revit snoop identifies them in Category OST_Viewers and their family type is Building Elevation. How do I hide ALL elevation elements from the image?